# NSFetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults: doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, core-data, fault

I'm working on an application based on Core Data.  I'm doing a fetch on `Item`. I don't want the fetched objects to be fault when returned because I'm sure they will be accessed immediately.  Thus, I set the `returnsObjectsAsFaults` to be `NO`. However, it doesn't work for me.

Below is how I set up my `NSFetchedResultsController`.

```
NSString *cacheName = @"cache";
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:cacheName];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = APPDELEGATE.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[request setFetchBatchSize:20];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:cacheName];
[request release];

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL result = [frc performFetch:&error];
if(!result){
    NSLog(@"Unresolved core data error");
}
```

Any ideas?

Update: Actually, all the fetched objects are  faults.

```
<_PFBatchFaultingArray 0x176f2bc0>(
<Item: 0x17613480> (entity: Item; id: 0x18ba3910 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p610> ; data: <fault>),
<Item: 0x18b832e0> (entity: Item; id: 0x176dda50 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p611> ; data: <fault>),
<Item: 0x18b97040> (entity: Item; id: 0x18b5f830 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p612> ; data: <fault>),
<Item: 0x18bd1d40> (entity: Item; id: 0x18bc2f30 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p613> ; data: <fault>),
<Item: 0x18b996c0> (entity: Item; id: 0x18b8f660 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p619> ; data: <fault>)
)
```

Comment: explain us what do you mean with *it does not work for me*

Comment: Do you have any logs/tests (CoreData debug logs) showing excessive faulting?

Comment: @flexaddicted The fetched objects are still faults.

Comment: @DanShelly What do u mean with  "excessive faulting"? Thanks.

Comment: @Libra, Do you see in the CoreData debug logs any faults that are not fulfilled in batches? The FRC is managing the faulting, try executing the request directly on the context and see if you get faults or fulfilled object.

Comment: @DanShelly, Yes. actually, log shows fetched objects are all faults. I've edited the question and appended logs.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed this as well. In my case, I was fetching the results on a child context. When I changed the fetch to be on the main context, then `returnsObjectsAsFaults` was behaving properly.

Again, if I did the fetch from a child context, `returnsObjectsAsFaults` did not work as expected.

Someone was having a similar issue here, for the same reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14801402/1060314

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem. I was fetching on a background context.